# Extract values from a text

Tags: java

I've log like following from test run results and from which I have to extract count of total run tests, passed tests, failed tests, skipped tests etc

```
[INFO] Results:\n" +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[ERROR] Errors: \n" +
                "[ERROR]   AttachRestTest>GenericRestBase.pre:102 » Business I/O error on GET request for...\n" +
                "[ERROR]   CallbackActionRestTest>GenericRestBase.pre:102 » Business I/O error on GET req...\n" +
                "[ERROR]   CountRestTest>GenericRestBase.pre:102 » Business I/O error on GET request for ..." +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[ERROR] Tests run: 55, Failures: 0, Errors: 44, Skipped: 0\n" +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In order to do that I got line with results details using following code -

```
String content = "[INFO] Results:\n" +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[ERROR] Errors: \n" +
                "[ERROR]   AttachRestTest>GenericRestBase.pre:102 » Business I/O error on GET request for...\n" +
                "[ERROR]   CallbackActionRestTest>GenericRestBase.pre:102 » Business I/O error on GET req...\n" +
                "[ERROR]   CountRestTest>GenericRestBase.pre:102 » Business I/O error on GET request for ..." +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[ERROR] Tests run: 55, Failures: 0, Errors: 44, Skipped: 0\n" +
                "[INFO] \n" +
                "[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Tests run(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

        if(matcher.find()) {
              String foundText = matcher.group();
        }
```

It gives me following value in `foundText` -

```
Tests run: 55, Failures: 0, Errors: 44, Skipped: 0
```

Now I want to extract, total count, failurs, Errors, Skipped etc.

I can use `split()` method over that string but that would make code lengthy and not reliable.

Is there any better way in Java I can extract those values?

**Notes:** Because of some limitations in my project, I cannot use libraries which are not part of Java. I mean no extra jar or maven dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using split after removing non-digit characters with regex?

```
String str = "Tests run: 55, Failures: 0, Errors: 44, Skipped: 0";
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+"," ").trim();
str.split(" "); // [55, 0, 44, 0]
```

Comment: This sound too much better than what I had done, which was lengthy and not easily readable. Thanks Guy!